# integer promotion in c# (the range of an sbyte as an example)

Tags: c#

so I am studying about Integer Promotion and I know that  type promotions only apply to the values operated upon when an expression is evaluated.
I have this example where I take an sbyte that is equal to 127 and increment it by 1 and then I output it on the Console and I get a -128. Does this mean that the sbyte turns into an int during the process of incrementing and then it somehow transforms into a -128.
I would like to know how exactly this happens.

```
        sbyte efhv = 127;
        efhv++;
        Console.WriteLine(efhv);
```

Comment: Numeric promotion does not apply to `++`. Please see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11472-unary-numeric-promotions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because this is a signed 8-bit integer. When the value exceeds the max it overflows into the negative numbers. It is not promotion but overflow behavior you are seeing.

To verify:

```cs
sbyte efhv = 127;
efhv++;
Console.WriteLine(efhv);

Console.WriteLine(sbyte.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine(sbyte.MinValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

As @Sweeper pointed out in the comments, integer promotion does not apply to the `++` operator: `++` modifies the value in-place, which means that the modified value must be within the range of the
specified data type. Integer promotion would not make any sense here.

As @beautifulcoder explained in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71720992/7724), the effect you see is simply [a two's complement number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) overflowing, since C# [executes arithmetic operations in an unchecked context by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked-and-unchecked).

According to the [C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11471-general) integer promotion *does* occur for the unary `+` and the binary `+` operators, as can be seen in the following code example:

```
sbyte efhv = 127;
sbyte one = 1;

Console.WriteLine((efhv).GetType().Name);       // prints SByte
Console.WriteLine((efhv++).GetType().Name);     // prints SByte
Console.WriteLine((+efhv).GetType().Name);      // prints Int32
Console.WriteLine((efhv + one).GetType().Name); // prints Int32
```

([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAfq8Q))